# spark RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset) can be updated?

Tags: apache-spark

RDD can be updated?  --- i.e.  suppose we created a RDD from "a.txt" file.  "a.txt" got updated. is possible to update RDD without reading entire file a.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD are immutable by definition hence you want be able to change the RDD when the "a.txt" file changes.